# jQuery select all SVG paths and apply animate fill

Tags: jquery, path, svg, selector

I have a working country map that with regions that animates fill on click and on hover. Each path works individually.

I would like to add a Select All/Clear All option that would apply the click effect to all the paths.
I created a new div with

```
<div id="selectAll">Click to Select All</div>
```

and then with some jQuery

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(){
  $("[id^=Co]").animate({
         fill: '#698B22'
         }, 300);
});
```

The selector `"[id^=Co]"` can get to all the paths as all their id's start with 'Co'. This selector also works perfectly with my qtip for each region.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any guidance would be a great help.
tia

Comment: `animate` function does not recognize `fill` effect. Are you using some plugin or what ? If you need to animate color, you need jQuery Color plugin: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned: yes I am using **raphael.js** and currently on hover works with 
`obj.hover(function(){this.animate({fill: '#32CD32'}, 300);},`etc.

I'm trying to find some way of selecting all the obj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your select operation you'd have to get the raphaël objects somehow to use raphaël's animation functionality. Not sure if that's possible.

But you could create a raphaël [`set`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set) of the paths you need to change later, and then just change the fill on that `set` on click.

Comment: How I eventually got all regions to change colour:
`$('#selectAll').click(function(){
   $("#map path").attr({fill: '#698B22'});`

without animation though, I'll live...

An example of a path I use with Raphael
`Mayo: {name: 'Mayo',value: 'notSelected',path: 'm85.529,143.84497c-0.271,0.01599z'},` etc.(truncated for display)

On click of a path the value **notSelected** is changed to **isSelected** with `paths[arr[this.id]].value = "isSelected";` and that way I can control if hover should change the colour.

Comment: So when the div **selectAll**' is clicked all paths should change colour and all their values should be set to **isSelected**.
I'm still new to **json** and although I have built a complete messenger app in Java using XML I am unfamiliar with jQuery and parsing **json**. I tried using a for loop with no luck.
I think perhaps I've been staring at this SVG/Raphael task for too long :)

Comment: Be aware that if you do it with jQuery like this it probably won't display correctly in old IE versions (the ones using VML). Basically what I'm saying is: it's a bad idea to mix in jQuery unless you're sure you'll only need to support SVG-capable browsers. And if you're sure you can require SVG then http://d3js.org is much closer to what you want because it doesn't hide the svg elements like Raphaël does, and it's similar to jQuery in that selectors is a core concept.

Comment: thank you very much for that link, very kewl stuff. 
I have this old example of what I'm working on http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/09101916/trazoo/demo_1/ and it does work on IE6 albeit very slowly. Also I can't use `toFront()`... even on IE9.

Answer (score 3):

add the jquery.color plugin, then add before your code:

```
  jQuery.Color.hook( "fill stroke" );
```

then your original animate function will work

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(){
  $("[id^=Co]").animate({
         fill: '#698B22'
         }, 300);
});
```